# Add SSL support to Python for existing Plone 3.3.4 install

Tags: python, ssl, plone, bootstrapping, buildout

I have an existing Plone 3.3.4 installation that was created using the Unified Installer.  The python packaged with the Unified Installer does not include SSL support.  How would I go about adding SSL support to an existing installation?  Do i need to rebuild python, then run bootstrap and buildout to get have it enabled?  Or is it something that can simply be added to buildout as an egg?

I am able to create a seperate python build(2.4.6) with SSL support, but am having trouble using that python version to run bootstrap.py.:

```
File "bootstrap.py", line 53, in ?

    PYTHONPATH=

AssertionError
```

It looks like it should be getting the PYTHONPATH from setuptools, so are there some changes i need to make there?

Am i going about this the wrong way?  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
DR

Answer (score 4):

Easiest path: re-run the unified installer, specifying a different target. If it finds libssl this time, you're set. If not, try again, and use --with-python to pick your python2.4.6 that has ssl support. And, you might as well update to 3.3.6 while you're at it.

Alternatively, install distribute for your new Python 2.6.4, then try bootstrapping again. Distribute will give you setuptools -- with fewer bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The universal installer will build with [SSL by default](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installing-on-linux-unix-bsd/command-line-options) and will acctually stop if it can't find the development libraries and headers it needs to build SSL support unless you explicitly use the `--without-ssl` libraries.  Is that what you did?

Comment: I'm trying to add SSL support to python so that i can use it with the mail functionality.  I already have SSL enabled on the web server and https is working fine.

I want to use a gmail smtp server as my mail server, but it seems to be having trouble because SSL is not enabled in python.

Comment: The issue I'm having is the same as the one described in this thread:|
http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Can-t-send-mail-via-external-server-td351661.html

Comment: That does *not* mean that Python doesn't have SSL support.  Please elaborate as to how you concluded that Python was built without SSL.

Comment: from python:
`
import urllib2

f = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com")

`
urlopen error unknown
 url type: https

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow is stripping away some of my text...  i get the same error as shown here:
http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/628/

Comment: Thanks Ross.  Yes, that test also comes up as False when i'm using the python installed with Plone.

Comment: So did you do what I asked in my answer?

Comment: i didn't use the --without-ssl tag, so i guess it didn't find the libraries.  Does that mean i need to install openssl in linux before I run the unified installer?  If i've already installed plone, is there a way to do it after the fact?

Comment: the Unified installed ran successfully, and i didn't use the --without-ssl tag, but no SSL was installed with python.

Comment: I think that the ssl check and --without-ssl flag were added only in the 4.x series of the installer. That means that finding ssl is left up to the python install -- which is usually pretty good about finding it if it's installed in any of the traditional places.